# Find relating equation of M and N

Tags: probability-distributions

P$X$(X)= Me^(-2|x|) + Ne^(-3|x|)  is the probability density function for the real random variable X over the entire axis , M andN Both are positive real number . What will be the equation relating M and N?

I considered it as a exponential function and i integrate it -infinity to infinity  f($x$) dx=1 
But it not generate correct answer 
.
Ans is
 M+ (2/3)N =1

Answer (score 1):

Taking advantage of symmetry, integrate $Me^{-2x}+Ne^{-3x}$ from $0$ to $\infty$, and set the result equal to $1/2$.

We get $(1/2)M+(1/3)N=1/2$.

Alternately, integrate $Me^{-2x}+Ne^{-3x}$ from $0$ to $\infty$, double, and set the result equal to $1$.